# Как правильно понять последовательность действий

Tags: java

Столкнулся с такой последовательностью на javarush и не совсем понятен один вопрос. Разъясните пожалуйста популярно.
1. Создали 2 новых объекта. murzik так сказать ненулевой. vaska - нулевой.
2. А вот потом vaska=murzik и после этого murzik = null; Я так это понимаю - Нулевому объекту Васька мы присвоили ненулевое значение Мурзика. Соответственно теперь Васька и Мурзик должны обладать равным и ненулевым значением. А тут все наоборот - Мурзик почему-то стал null...

```
Cat murzik = new Cat();
Cat vaska = null;
vaska = murzik;
murzik = null;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Cat murzik = new Cat();
```

Создаём новый объект класса Cat, ссылку на него запоминаем в переменной `murzik`.

```
Cat vaska = null;
```

Создаём переменную `vaska` для хранения ссылки на объект класса Cat. Инициализируем как null, т.е. переменная не хранит ссылки ни на какой созданный объект.

```
vaska = murzik;
```

Копируем значение ссылки из переменной `murzik` в переменную `vaska`. Теперь две переменные хранят ссылки на один и тот же объект.

```
murzik = null;
```

Обнуляем ссылку `murzik`. Теперь `vaska` ссылается на созданный ранее объект, а `murzik` нет.

Comment: То есть в итоге после того как мы скопировали значение переменной murzik в переменную vaska мы получили Cat vaska = new Cat();   А ссылку murzik мы в конце просто сами обнулили?

Comment: Нет, `new Cat()` это создание нового объекта класса Cat. В приведённом коде создаётся один объект. Грубо говоря, объект это область памяти, в которой хранятся его данные (например, имя кота, его вес, порода и т.п.). Переменная может содержать ссылку на эту область памяти (адрес). На один и тот же объект могут ссылаться сколько угодно переменных.

Answer (score 1):

В четвертой строке вы обнулили murzik, поэтому он пустой.